# ERROR APPCRASH (Python dejo de funcionar) al querer ejecutar el administrador del panel de control de Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola estoy intentado acceder al panel de control de django pero me aparece este error APPCRASH,

Nombre del evento de problema: APPCRASH
  Nombre de la aplicación:  python.exe
  Versión de la aplicación: 3.7.112.1013
  Marca de tiempo de la aplicación: 5a961341
  Nombre del módulo con errores:    python37.dll
  Versión del módulo con errores:   3.7.112.1013

intente descargando el modulo python37.dll pero aun continuo con el error.

El error solo aparece cuando ejecuto 127.0.0.1:8000/admin..

anterior a esto logre creear el superusuario sin ningun problema..